# Unity 3D How to project a Vector3 onto a plane or get angle between two Vector3s in a specific plane?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I am trying to program a third person character such that when a direction key, eg. D is pressed, if the character is currently facing same direction as camera, Right Quarter Turn animation is played, if it is facing the camera, Left Quarter Turn is played, similar to GTA V. But I am having trouble getting angles between camera and player in the Y plane. I tried this into the player control script:

```
void Right()
    {
        Vector3 pVec = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(transform.forward, Vector3.up);
        Vector3 cVec = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(mainCam.transform.forward, Vector3.up);
        print(cVec);
        float angle = Vector3.Angle(pVec, cVec);
        print(angle);
        if(angle >= 345 && angle <= 15)
        {
            animator.Play("StandQuarterTurnRight");
        }
        else if(angle >= 255 && angle <= 285)
        {
            animator.Play("StandHalfTurnRight");
        }
        else if(angle >= 165 && angle <= 195)
        {
            animator.Play("StandQuarterTurnLeft");
        }
        else if(angle >=75 && angle <= 105)
        {
            float forw = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            if (forw > 0.5f && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) forw = 0.5f;
            else if (forw < -0.5f && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) forw = -0.5f;
            animator.SetFloat("Speed", forw);
        }
    }
```

But it is not working, I get wrong angles. I is giving me 90 when character faces right or left of camera forward, and wrong angles for others and it doesn't give 180+ at all, what am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to achieve what I am trying?

Comment: Try trigonometry or Quaternions https://answers.unity.com/questions/54495/how-do-i-convert-angle-to-vector3.html

Comment: What is with the down vote? what is wrong with my question?

Answer (score 1):

I would transform the viewdirection of the camera into the coordinate system of your character. Then it is very easy so see where you want him to turn or move.

Assuming your camera's rotation is at `mainCam.transform.rotation`, you can use this code:

```
float target_angle = 90.0f; // assuming want to turn 'right'.

// direction of camera, in worldspace.
Vector3 cam_dir = mainCam.transform.forward;
// now transform to a direction vector in character's local space.
cam_dir = transform.InverseTransformDirection(cam_dir);
// ignore y part, take X/Z to get the angle.
// 0 degrees is forward, 90 deg is toward positive X, so normally right.
float cam_angle = Mathf.Atan2(cam_dir.x,cam_dir.z)*Mathf.Rad2Deg;

// angle we need to turn
float turn_angle = target_angle - cam_angle;
// [.....] do it now.
```

Using the InverseTransformXxx() function is often very helpful if trying to think in some character's local view. You could also transform the camera's position into the character's space by using `char.transform.InverseTransformPoint(mainCam.transform.position)` and use that for some reference.

Comment: The problem is my camera's forward is not in the Y player, the camera is slightly above the player and is tilted downwards, so the angle measured is in 3D. I want the angle just in the Y plane

Comment: That is just what it does. It transforms the camera-view into the localspace of the player, which still includes some negative component on Y. Along with the X and Z. See the comment `ignore y part, ...` . Dropping Y there flattens the projected camera direction vector to the Y plane.

Comment: I like this approach. @ShantanuShinde Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a small fix to your code, which adjusts your result to work, without changing anything else:**

```
void Right()
{
    Vector3 pVec = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(transform.forward, Vector3.up);
    Vector3 cVec = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(mainCam.transform.forward, Vector3.up);
    print(cVec);

    float angleA = Vector3.Angle(pVec, cVec); //Get the angle between the 2 vectors, projected on Y-plane
    float perspectiveAngle = Vector3.Angle(transform.right, cVec); //Get the angle between camera and player's right vector
    float angle = angleA; //In case angle is below 180, angle is AngleA

    if (perspectiveAngle > 90f) //If angle between player's right vector and camera is > 90, then we need to adjust the angle, as it is equal to or greater than 180
        angle = 360f - angleA;

    print(angle);
    if (angle >= 345 && angle <= 15)
    {
        animator.Play("StandQuarterTurnRight");
    }
    else if (angle >= 255 && angle <= 285)
    {
        animator.Play("StandHalfTurnRight");
    }
    else if (angle >= 165 && angle <= 195)
    {
        animator.Play("StandQuarterTurnLeft");
    }
    else if (angle >= 75 && angle <= 105)
    {
        float forw = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        if (forw > 0.5f && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) forw = 0.5f;
        else if (forw < -0.5f && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) forw = -0.5f;
        animator.SetFloat("Speed", forw);
    }
}
```

**See the comments above, which sort of describe how it works. Hopefully that helps**

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against using angles here as much as possible. Instead, You can use dot products between the camera's right and the player's local directions to determine which local direction is most in-line with the camera's right direction. Explanation in comments.

```
void Right()
{
    float dotThreshold = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.PI * 0.25f); 

    // Take the dot products between the camera's right and  
    // each direction from the player. 
    // Either exactly one dot product will exceed this threshold 
    // (sin 45 degrees) or two will equal it.
    // Either way, when we see one dot product >= the threshold, 
    // we know what direction we should face.

    Vector3 camRight = mainCam.transform.right;

    if(Vector3.Dot(camRight, transform.right) >= dotThreshold) 
    {
        // camera's right ~ player's right
        animator.Play("StandQuarterTurnRight");
    }
    else if(Vector3.Dot(camRight, -transform.forward) >= dotThreshold) 
    {
        // camera's right ~ player's back
        animator.Play("StandHalfTurnRight");
    }
    else if(Vector3.Dot(camRight, -transform.right) >= dotThreshold)
    {
        // camera's right ~ player's left
        animator.Play("StandQuarterTurnLeft");
    }
    else
    {
        // camera's right ~ player's forward
        float forw = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        if (forw > 0.5f && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) forw = 0.5f;
        else if (forw < -0.5f && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) forw = -0.5f;
        animator.SetFloat("Speed", forw);
    }
}
```

If you can't assume that the player and the camera have the same y axis direction, you must project into the same plane as done in the question:

```
void Right()
{
    float dotThreshold = Mathf.Sin(Mathf.PI * 0.25f); 

    // Take the dot products between the camera's right and  
    // each direction from the player. 
    // Either exactly one dot product will exceed this threshold 
    // (sin 45 degrees) or two will equal it.
    // Either way, when we see one dot product >= the threshold, 
    // we know what direction we should face.

    Vector3 camRight = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(mainCam.transform.right, Vector3.up);
    Vector3 playerRight = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(transform.right, Vector3.up);
    Vector3 playerForward = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(transform.forward, Vector3.up);

    if(Vector3.Dot(camRight, playerRight) >= dotThreshold) 
    {
        // camera's right ~ player's right
        animator.Play("StandQuarterTurnRight");
    }
    else if(Vector3.Dot(camRight, -playerForward) >= dotThreshold) 
    {
        // camera's right ~ player's back
        animator.Play("StandHalfTurnRight");
    }
    else if(Vector3.Dot(camRight, -playerRight) >= dotThreshold)
    {
        // camera's right ~ player's left
        animator.Play("StandQuarterTurnLeft");
    }
    else
    {
        // camera's right ~ player's forward
        float forw = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        if (forw > 0.5f && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) forw = 0.5f;
        else if (forw < -0.5f && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) forw = -0.5f;
        animator.SetFloat("Speed", forw);
    }
}
```